# Javascript exceptions within qml property bindings

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt5, qt-creator

I seem to not understand how exceptions interact with property bindings:

```
TextField {
id:root
text: rebind()

function rebind(){
    root.text = Qt.binding(function(){
        try{
            return accessor.getValue()
        }
        catch(e){
            root.text = "Incorrect property: " + usedParam;
            throw e;
        }
    })
}
```

I am throwing an exception in getValue function, that is correctly displayed in qt creator... until I insert this try catch block. Then I get the diagnostic text in TexField's input field but an exception I am rethrowing after an assignment just vanishes into thin air... no more indication of anything in qtcreator. what's the deal here?

UPD: the answer from Stepehen Quan raises a ton of valid points about the code which I am thankful for(and will rewrite the code locally), but doesn't answer the question where is the exception from `throw e` lost in the internals of qt... which is kinda the main point.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many errors:

1. `text: rebind()` your calling `rebind()` as a function.
2. You're attempting to assign `root.text = Qt.binding()...` with a property binding
3. The value being evaluated does not appear to have any property binding behavior `return accessor.getValue()`
4. The error case `root.text = "Incorrect property: " + usedParam;` is assigning the error in a different way

Also, I don't recommend naming any property as `root`. To solve some of the problems, look at the following changes:

```
TextField {
    id: textField
    text: getValue()
}

Text {
    id: errorText
}

function getValue() {
    try {
        errorText.text = "";
        return accessor.getValue();
    } catch (err) {
        errorText.text = err.message;
        throw err;
    }
}
```

The bottom tries to clean up your example with the following changes:

1. Implement getValue() as a true function that merely returns a value with some exception handling
2. Assign it to `textField.text`

The problem with the above is how `accessor.getValue()` can have any property-binding behavior as there do not appear to be changeable inputs.

You also seem to want to look at an imperative version of the above, so, for completeness, I show you that pattern as well:

```
TextField {
    id: textField
}

Text {
    id: errorText
}

function getValue() {
    try {
        errorText.text = "";
        return accessor.getValue();
    } catch (err) {
        errorText.text = err.message;
        throw err;
    }
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    textField.text = Qt.binding(getValue);
}
```

So here, you see that I replaced:

```
TextField {
    id: textField
    text: getValue()
}
```

with

```
TextField {
    id: textField
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    textField.text = Qt.binding(getValue);
}
```

The `Component.onCompleted` isn't exactly what you're shown. I just choose an arbitrary event handler to put the code in. You could have choosen a different event handler, e.g. Button onClicked or some other deferred event to put that code in. Why you want to do that is to execute the code later. But, the `Qt.binding` syntax is somewhat harder to master, and, if you can avoid it with appropriate declarative syntax, that would be preferred.

In the example below, I wrap `eval()` with an exception handler and implement both a declarative and imperative example of calling it:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        width: parent.width
        Label { text: qsTr("Input") }
        TextField {
            id: input
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            text: "3 + 4"
        }
        Label { text: qsTr("Declarative Example") }
        TextField {
            Layout.fillWidth: text
            text: evaluate(input.text)
        }
        Label { text: qsTr("Imperative Example") }
        TextField {
            id: result2
            Layout.fillWidth: text
            Component.onCompleted: {
                result2.text = Qt.binding(() => evaluate(input.text))
            }
        }
    }
    function evaluate(stmt) {
        try {
            return eval(stmt);
        } catch (err) {
            return err.message;
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAADR3icnZLBbsIwDIbvfQqrp1aTeth2ArEL2yQkDkNC2jm0BqKlSec4DIT67ksIAsoYYvMhauw/fz6nlnVjiGHCEyfLj0R2tsXQaCaj7Hl+LDbGsU3exAJhm4CPoVGu1rGwT4X4khUve9AIQs3FbneojcUMFWyBcc09+LRTytKRbhynObQH1dRXXyWq6sQ1hKx6IIO6k40AxVwq9R6vZnLYkcTr0ge4g8f0UGmvYj1jqQQJliuEl7WoG4U3QV7A8coLOLgSygnGbNdSEZL5jWyjusF/oIX3I7RO8f1fkYfGj4MOP9To8K2Q0bt1/UPs/XftwMCPTzGTupJ6kWU5DJ4udp13XNqzR4jr3OmSpdFHA8s15ycETJszHkJ2FE9Edf9oDaXgcgkZEuW/HCMqarTWD3z/B1KbfAPdmOgP)

Comment: accessor has some reevaluatable parameters it calls inside getvalue so it actually works as intended. as in - the code in my example actually works as intended and passes a ton of tests for all the intended functionality it needs to have, the only thing I can't fathom what happens with is exceptions. 


But I am willing admit i am a qml newbie and will welcome any advice

Comment: oh, right, I am not returning value from rebind am I? huh, how is it even passing all the test then, wow. I seem to have edited the code one time too many

Comment: ```root.text = Qt.binding().``` is actually how the documentation has it: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html

Comment: ```assigning the error in a different way``` completely intentional. this is breaking the binding on purpose.

Comment: In summary, the core point I'm trying to make is it is either declarative `text: someFunc()`  or imperative `root.text = Qt.binding(someFunc)`. It is not declarative and imperative at the same time. i.e. `text: Qt.binding(someFunc)` is incorrect. Plus the numerous other issues I raised with your snippet.

Comment: The updated snippet kinda misses the point again: I can catch this exception like you did in the online example  in my own code too. the actual question is where does it vanish to if I rethrow it from that catching function. Both qt creator suddenly stops seeing this exception AND I cannot seem to find a way to catch it at the place the value of getValue*( dependant property is changed programmatically.

The question is what happens to the exception after it leaves the boundary of the class it was thrown in and why qtcreator can display the original exception but not rethrown one.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: I am thankful that you took the time to write the extended answer and I didn't even realize you can do online testing like that so thanks for that too, it just kinda misses the original question .

Comment: Okay, what is the objective you're looking for? Because if you rethrow an exception, you're preventing your function from returning. That's the point of an exception. Either you return something or your abort execution and throw an exception. You can't have both. You decide what you want to do. I am struggling to answer your question because you cannot have both.